# Errors reporting after i type public int a

Tags: c#

I have a simple program, WITHOUT "public int a;", the program runs no problem,

but after add "public int a;", the programm has errors, what is the problem?

there is no special meaning for this int field "a", i just want to try something and find this problem

[image]

Comment: For future reference, please post code and errors as text, not a screenshot.

Comment: @DStanley i want to show the red error lines, so use image...

Comment: @user3339999 red lines doesn't tell us anything about the error.

Comment: This question is very basic, but valid and well-asked. Don't downvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare fields and properties at the class level, not the method:

```
class Program
{
   public int a;
   ...
}
```

Because the access modifier has meaning in this context. In your method you can only have local variables and they can only be accessed from the method that they declared. Curly-braces determine the scope of local variables.So specifying an access modifier for them is not allowed.

Comment: thanks! but why i can write int "number" in the main method, "number" is also a field. I removed "public" then the program is ok. What is wrong with "public"? I know it is a silly question, but really no idea why

Comment: @user3339999 public is an access modifier. which determines the accessibility level of a member of your class. you can't declare class members inside of the method.

Comment: Thanks! now i know local variables can not have access modifier

Answer (score 0):

just use:

```
int a
```

as the word "public" is reserved for Class Variables / methods

Comment: hi, little penguin, now i know the reason is local variables can not have access modifier